# How would I place a random generated number in a form field?

Tags: php, random, passwords, generated

Like this:

form:
title - [         ]
description - [         ]
password - [         ]

> Don't want your own password?
>   [Generate one]

And then the [Generate one] button will just place a random number in the password field or whatever field desired.

How would I do this?

I was thinking that this would do it:

```
function generate() {
$placerand = rand();
}
```

and then place it in the 'value' of the form field.

```
<form>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $placerand; ?>" placeholder="password">
<input type="submit" onclick="generate()" value="Generate a random number"><>
</form>
```

but, I'm thinking that the php function is a javascript function, so that wouldn't work...
Would it?

Comment: Sounds like a job for JavaScript. Look up `math.random()` and `document.getElementById` as well as `element.value`.

Comment: Yeah, my thought process was leaning more towards javascript... do you know of any tutorials I could run by to understand this kind of funtion a little more, @DaveChen ?

Comment: point to note here is that PHP is parsed before HTML and Javascript.So you will have t go for JQuery or else u would require page refresh.

Comment: That is, if the number is generated server-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example

```js
function GetRandom() {
  var myElement = document.getElementById("pwbx")
  myElement.value = Math.random()
}
```

```html
<input type="Textbox" id="pwbx" />
<button OnClick="GetRandom()" type="button">generate</button>
```

Comment: debugger can be safely removed, I left it in there for testing. It basically means what when you have the debug window open in chrome, it will pause the webpage and let you step through individual lines of code. I will remove it now

Comment: I'll give that a try, it looks like that would work though. I will give you the accepted answer as soon as I can.

Comment: I tested it in a XAMPP sandbox, it definitely works. If you need help applying it to your particular situation just ask

Answer (score 1):

I used you same code and i achieved what you really wanted, this is how i got it done (working):

```
    <?php
srand ((double) microtime() * 1000000);
$random3 = rand(1000,9999);
?>
<?php echo $random3; ?>
<form>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $random3; ?>" placeholder="password">
<input type="submit" onclick="generate()" value="Generate a random number">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

first you can use javascript math.random() , it will output a random number each time it is called. Place it anywhere you want on onclick event

```
function sampleExplanation(){
 var x = jQuery("#demo");
 x.html(Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1));

}
```

"demo" id of the element where the data will be placed.

this is  sample function which will generate random numbers between 1 - 10. In a same way you can write your own function to generate a random number in any range.

Comment: Incoming minus ones (I won't downvote though), you don't need jQuery for this :P

Comment: Actually I always go with jQuery, its kind of stick to my mind. And yes its not necessary required to always use jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

one-liner to generate strings:

```
<?php
substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789',5)),0,5);
?>
```

The strings can be repeated to have the possibility that a character appears multiple times.
You can increase the size I have set it to `5`